# is there any way in django rest framework to list all devices a user logged in?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to mimic goggle account's feature of listing all devices and terminate session from devices is there any approach with to create this feature using django rest framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Django AuthUser with a Custom User Model and add field with devices.